# SQuirreL SQL connection refused error

Tags: unix, ubuntu-14.04, informix, squirrel-sql

I'm a bit of a newb when it comes to Linux and Informix so please bear with me.
I am running the latest version of SQuirreL and trying to connect to the DB on my server running on VirtualBox with Ubuntu 14.04 and using Informix for the DB. I keep getting a connection refused error. The URL on SQuirreL is:

*jdbc:informix-sqli://IP_ADDRESS:9088/vegas_db:INFORMIXSERVER=ol_vegas*

I ran netstat -l and got this output:

Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)

Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8940 /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8102     @/com/ubuntu/upstart

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9344     /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9677     /var/run/samba/nmbd/unexpected

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9886     /var/run/acpid.socket

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10465    /var/run/cups/cups.sock

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10015    /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/b6bc3ec8e4ad716ba15c54a6cd6aa136

unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     8403     /run/udev/control

and my sqlhosts file has this in it:

*ol_vegas onsoctcp scott-xact ids_port*

I noticed that the server isn't listening on port 9088 is there any way to make it?

Comment: try changing the hostname for a  * in the sqlhosts file and bounce the engine.  (like 'ol_vegas onsoctcp * ids_port')  That will tell the server to spawn a listener thread for each network interface (eth0/lo/etc)

Comment: Its still giving me the connection refused error

Comment: is your server up and running? can you connect with dbaccess to 'ol_vegas'?. A telnet to the port (whatever port correspond to ids_port) should also show you if the client can reach the ids server or not.

Comment: The server is up and running, and I can connect using dbaccess, I'm just trying to find what the value of ids_port is.

Comment: ids_port is defined in your /etc/services file.

Comment: Adding the asterisk worked, i just didn't reboot after changing the sqlhosts file. Thanks for the help